# Azure data factory dataflow activity get request does not add additional headers along with URL

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to use ADF dataflow activity web source to receive a JSON response. But it seems like the additional headers I have included in the "Source Options" section does not get sent along with the URL. because of that I'm getting a "401" response.

How to resolve this issue.

[Source Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nnh0h.png)

I've tried different URLs. Even different ADF environments. same 401 error output since the additional headers won't be included in the get request.

In web activities the particular URL works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

> But it seems like the additional headers I have included in the "Source Options" section does not get sent along with the URL. because of that I'm getting a "401" response.

[image]

The cause of error would be dataflow is not able to detect headers properly or values you are passing to headers are incorrect.

**I tried with sample URL and passed the `Authorization` token as header and `content-type` and worked fine for me.**

**Follow below process:**

- Create string parameter in Data flow for `Authorization` header.
  [image]
- Then pass this parameter in header value and pass other headers as your requirement

```json
Authorization : $parameter1
Content-Type : 'application/json'
```

[image]

- Then in pipeline select data flow under parameter  pass the pipeline expression for the parameter as `Bearer @{activity('Web1').output.data.Token}` as per your web activity result.
  [image]

**This will take correct headers and get the data from Rest Api**

***OUTPUT***

[image]